# How to make KeyDown and KeyUp on android device?

Tags: java, android, biometrics

I have a question.

I'm making [Keystroke dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics) app on android devices.

For now, I make an Activity with measure string and `EditText`. I want to catch `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events on software keyboard.

My question is, what is the best way to catch `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` on Android with Java? If `EditText` is a good choice? If it have methods to catch any keypresses?

[image]

**EDIT**

I want to detect keys from string above and measure time of pressing it, (start measure on `KeyDown` and stop on `KeyUp` for example). If its possible, i want to block other keys that is not mentioned in my `test string` (its **`9RJhl6aH0n`**, like in my screen)

**EDIT2**

What i achieve so far is something like this, but my app crashes on `default`, when I coded line: `measureText.setText("")`. It works pretty ok, but still it won't trigger on `KeyDown` (or `KeyPress`). These methods run only on `KeyUp`, when user just typed letter. Order is very important!

```
measureText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            switch(measureText.getText().toString()){
                case "9":
                    break;
                case "9R":
                    break;
                case "9RJ":
                    break;
                case "9RJh":
                    break;
                case "9RJhl":
                    break;
                case "9RJhl6":
                    break;
                case "9RJhl6a":
                    break;
                case "9RJhl6a0":
                    break;
                case "9RJhl6a0n":
                    break;
                default:
                    measureText.getText().clear();
                    break;

            }
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You want to time key pressed? Or just detect key pressed?

Comment: I have a `test-string` (i added my view how it looks like). I want user to type that string. I want to verify, if he pressed the key with char that is mentioned with my `test-string`. When he press correct key, i start to measure time based on `stopwatch` or something like that in `Java`. it will be good if i could block opportunity to press keys that are not in my `test-string` that i pasted in my screen in my post

Comment: Use dispatch event @michasaucer

Comment: In `Android` documentation i cant find the way to use that in my case

Comment: Im looking for way to detect key press, and key leave

Comment: @michasaucer why are you not using textChangeListener for this purpose its a best suitable approach?

Comment: Because i dont want to hard-coded every single string to checking, if user type correctly. It will be something like `if("9")..if("9r")...if("9rl")...` and so on

Comment: I am putting my answer please have look you just override this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say, that `OnKeyUp` & `OnKeyDown` events won't cut it, because soft keyboards barely emit any of these. Here's a rough prototype, which filters the input of characters according to the expected string. there is lots of space for improvement; while a custom implementation is still a better approach than trying to use framework methods, which may only catch the <kbd>⌫</kbd> key... the `FilteredEditText` catches any input *before* it may appear on screen - in order to realize a keystroke pattern recorder, the expected string would need to be split into an `ArrayList`, which would also hold the duration in between the individual keystrokes; once recorded one can use the gathered information for comparison.

```
/**
 * Filtered {@link AppCompatEditText}
 * @author Martin Zeitler
 */
public class FilteredEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = FilteredEditText.class.getSimpleName();

    private String expectedString = null;

    public FilteredEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FilteredEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FilteredEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setExpectedString(@NonNull String value) {
        this.expectedString = value;
        this.setupInputFilter();
    }

    public void setupInputFilter() {
        this.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int destStart, int destEnd) {
                    if (source.length() > 0 && source.charAt(end-1) == expectedString.charAt(destEnd)) {

                        /* valid input received */
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "input accepted: " + String.valueOf(source.charAt(end-1)));
                        return source;

                    } else {

                        /* invalid input received */
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "input rejected: " + String.valueOf(source.charAt(end-1)) + " - expected: " + String.valueOf(expectedString.charAt(destEnd)));
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /** hardware event  */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onKeyDown()");
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    /** hardware event  */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onKeyUp()");
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
FilteredEditText mTextInput = findViewById(R.id.text_input);
mTextInput.setExpectedString("9RJhl6aH0n");
```

Logcat output:

```
D/FilteredEditText: input accepted: 9
D/FilteredEditText: input rejected: r - expected: R
D/FilteredEditText: input rejected: 4 - expected: R
D/FilteredEditText: input accepted: R
```

So far I've tested it with a software keyboard ...while I currently cannot test it with a BT hardware keyboard, because the batteries are empty. I'd assume, that the `InputFilter` catches all input.

That barely any `OnKeyUp` and `OnKeyDown` event is being triggered by software keyboards can be compensated, because when knowing when a keystroke is being filtered, this still leads to a comparable pattern - even if the duration of the keystroke cannot be measured, nor the attack velocity of the keystroke, due to the limitations of a software keyboard - the only possible workarounds would be enforcing hardware keyboards or creating a software keyboard which emits these events for all the keys (contrary to the default `GBoard`, nor `SwiftKey`). I'd just wonder about swipe-typing and voice-typing now ... because this is something barely considered by physical *keystroke* dynamics. even left a feedback for `GBoard`, because optionally emitting key-codes would be helpful in some cases.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands#java) also clearly states it:

> When handling keyboard events with the `KeyEvent` class and related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only from a hardware keyboard. You should never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

One can still use hardware events, while having buttons, which emit them; for example:

```
/**
 * Fake Hardware {@link AppCompatButton}
 * @see <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent">KeyEvent</a>
 * @author Martin Zeitler
 */
public class FakeHardwareButton extends AppCompatButton {

    private BaseInputConnection  mInputConnection;

    private int keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9;
    private KeyEvent keyDown;
    private KeyEvent keyUp;

    public FakeHardwareButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FakeHardwareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FakeHardwareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void setupInputConnection(View targetView) {

       this.mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(targetView, true);
       this.keyDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, this.keyCode);
       this.keyUp = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, this.keyCode);

       this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(keyDown);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(keyUp);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The issue is just, that eg. `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_9` are not the same, therefore one always has to compare the `String` representation in case of numeric keys.

Answer (score 3):

You just use dispatch event of activity

**Like this:**

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
        }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

By this, you can easily control the KeyDown and KeyUp event.

Here is you can find all [MotionEvents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent)

> In the case of Softkeys, you can only use `TextChangeListener`

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (arg0.toString()) {
                    case "9":
                        break;
                    case "9R":
                        break;
                    case "9RJ":
                        break;
                    case "9RJh":
                        break;
                    case "9RJhl":
                        break;
                    case "9RJhl6":
                        break;
                    case "9RJhl6a":
                        break;
                    case "9RJhl6a0":
                        break;
                    case "9RJhl6a0n":
                        break;
                    default:
                        arg0.clear();
                        break;

                }
                return;

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // here right logic for getting last char and show it on toast

        }

    });
```

Comment: What is Action Pointer? I want to catch keys like `K`, `A`, `SHIFT` etc. Read my original post again

Comment: I need more detailed answer. So you coded events on the screen? If user touch te screen, `ACTION_DOW` fired up?

Comment: @michasaucer yes

Comment: Make sense. I will check it in today or tomoroww. If it will be correct, i will mark your post as answer and i give u bounty

Comment: @michasaucer whenever the user touches the screen different action fired up.

Comment: I add the URL of MotionEvents docs please have the look @michasaucer

Comment: It will fired up even if user dont touch keyboard? do you know a possible way to block that function only for `EditText` or keyboard? Because if user will 
unwittingly touch the screen, it will fire your `dispatchTouchEvent`

Comment: you can add custom edit class which extended with edit text where you override this method which only calls when the edit text touches @michasaucer

Comment: If you know how to do it, could you provide your answer with this ?

Comment: @michasaucer I will provide it tomorrow is that ok??

Comment: Sure, i will wait then

Comment: @michasaucer there in android two type of cases on is hard keyboard and second one soft keyboard which is shown on screen so what you want actually??? hard keys or softkeys??

Comment: softtkeyboard ofc, that android device displaying

Comment: @michasaucer so there is no method to restrict the input characters only enters above string you just matched up by `TextChangeListener` after putting character by character.

Comment: because whenever you called on key or dispatch events it gets the gestures or hard keys values only you can check softkeys by `TextChangeListener` @michasaucer

Comment: Still, not an answer. Look into my  `EDIT3`

Comment: @michasaucer you can just match the string of which enter in the user in edit text you can't set the value in textChangeListener because its called itself to the infinite loop recursively so you just match the string and show error message you can't restrict to the user to don't add values.

Comment: yes, you can restrict to the user only ASCII characters or numeric characters only.

Comment: @michasaucerI updated my answer I think its perfect for you please have look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187432/discussion-between-tanveer-munir-and-michasaucer).

Comment: @michasaucer I think its more suitable for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You need to carefully override the following function:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
        {
            //your Action code
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and for the edittext :

```
mMyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, how this methods are related to `onKeyDown` and others?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [`dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

To detect the key pressed

Comment: How it works? It is listener, that listen to whole activity or i need to attach that method to my `EditText`? How to detect key (For example, `Shift`, `A`, `B` etc)? I need to start measuring time when user press and leave exact key as i mentioned in my original post

Comment: This listens in your activity

Comment: Is it possible, to detects key that i want to be detected? And how to do that?

Comment: You can map the keys, and in the KeyEvent detect if they were tapped, for example.

Comment: Something like `KeyEvent event == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A`? How i will know, if key is pressed or leaved? I need more detailed answers, because body of functions dont tells me too much